# Error While installing Ruby through RVM on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I am trying to install Ruby with Rails through  rvm. But is not working .. I am using this command `rvm requirements` .. and i am consulted this [document](http://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu/). How can i fixed this problem ..? `libyaml-dev` package still alive...? 
Thank you for reading.

Here is my command :

```
rvm requirements
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system...
Installing required packages: libyaml-dev, sqlite3, libgmp-dev, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libyaml-dev sqlite3 libgmp-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1465982191/package_install_libyaml-dev_sqlite3_libgmp-dev_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev.log
Package libgmp-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libyaml-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libyaml-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'sqlite3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgmp-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgdbm-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libncurses5-dev' has no installation candidate
+ return 100
+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Comment: It's my first time install ruby..

Comment: *Package libgmp-dev is not available*--Do a search on how to install that.  Then try installing rvm again.  Repeat as necessary.  Or, try `rbenv` instead.